# Error in Python Code when plotting in Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I am trying to plot distribution graph in python using `seaborn` . But I am getting error which I am not able to solve given below.

Code:

`sns.distplot(df['nn'])`

Error:

`cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Is there any efficient way to solve this by plotting histogram and the distribution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you have missing values in your "nn" variable and seaborn distplot does not handle missing values, you can remove the missing values when plotting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,np.nan], columns = ["nn"])
sns.distplot(df['nn'].dropna())
```

This will give you the plot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You provide very little info. However try to skip nan values like

```
df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
```

More examples:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html